# Emacs, AUCTeX and indentation of custom commands

Tags: emacs, indentation, auctex

I'm preparing a document that contains colored tables (using colortbl) and to correct the thin white lines that appear in those tables I'm using a custom new line macro to compensate for that. However, AUCTeX does not recognize the new macro and tries to indent the table in a strange way.

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering\sffamily
  \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \rowcolor{row1} \textbf{Nominative} & \emph{Wer?} & Who? \mynewline
                                                        \rowcolor{row2}\textbf{Accusative} & \emph{Wen?} & Who(m)? \\
    \rowcolor{row1} \textbf{Dative} & \emph{Wem?} & To who(m)? \\
    \rowcolor{row2} \textbf{Genitive} & \emph{Wessen?} & Whose? \mynewline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I make AUCTeX understand that `\mynewline` plays the same role as `\\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, AUCTeX should be able to learn about your own commands automatically if you set `TeX-parse-self` and `TeX-auto-save` to `t`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html#Parsing-Files

If that is not sufficient, you can tell AUCTeX about your own macros and environment using a style file. See https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Style-Files.html#Style-Files for more on this. It boils down to using the function `TeX-add-symbols` correctly.

Please note that it's been a few years since I last did this.

AUCTeX ships with a style file for longtable which seems to contain exactly what you need. See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style/longtable.el#n92

```
(TeX-add-symbols
    ;; Commands to end table rows
    '("endhead" 0)
    '("endfirsthead" 0)
    '("endfoot" 0)
    '("endlastfoot" 0)
    ;; Caption commands
    '("caption*" 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was kind of losing hope on getting an answer...

I added the symbols to the list but it's still not working, I'm not sure why. Now auctex knows about the custom linebreak command, but I'm not sure it knows how to indent for it, because the indentation is behaving the same way.

At the very least, this is a pointer for me. At least now I know what to look for!! =)